# Does this line in Python indicate that KNN is weighted?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-nn, mathematics

Does this line in Python indicate that KNN is weighted?

```py
clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5, metric='euclidean', weights='distance')
```

Are the weights the inverse of the distance?

Can anyone also give an example of how weighted KNN works mathematically?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the line indicates that KNN is weighted and that the weight is the inverse of the distance. All of this can easily be found in [scikit-learn's documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html)

Also, pro-tip, you can find an object's documentation using the `help` function. In this case:

```py
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

print(help(KNeighborsClassifier))
```

As to how weighted KNN works, I actually made a [learning unit](https://skratch.valentincalomme.com/learning-units/k-nearest-neighbours) on my website about this.

In short, weighting the instances means that instead of each neighbor having an equal vote, their vote is weighted. This means that if for instance, in my 3 nearest-neighbors, 2 of them are of class A but have low weights, and 1 of them is of class B and has a high weight, KNN might still pick class B even though more neighbors are of class A.

Comment: Thank you. I know the logic of wknn but I meant mathematically. I need to see this code line as equations. I would be grateful if you can help

Comment: the wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) already provides some more mathematical foundation